# SQL select parent-child recursively based on a reference table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I saw many questions related to a recursive query but couldn't find any that shows how to use it based on a reference table.

I have a `MasterTable` where `Id`, `ParentId` columns are establishing the parent/child relation.

I have a `SubTable` where I have a bunch of Ids which could be a parent Id or child Id.

I would like to retrieve all related records *(parent or child, recursively)* from the `MasterTable` based on given `SubTable`

Current output:

```
id          parentId
----------- -----------
1           NULL
2           1
3           1
4           NULL
5           4
6           5
7           6
```

Expected output

```
id          parentId
----------- -----------
1           NULL
2           1
3           1
4           NULL
5           4
6           5
7           6
8           9
9           NULL
10          NULL
11          10
13          11
14          10
15          16
16          NULL
```

Comparison of actual vs expected:

[image]

Code:

```sql
DECLARE @MasterTable TABLE
(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    parentId INT NULL
);

DECLARE @SubTable TABLE
(
    id INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @MasterTable (id, parentId)
VALUES (1, NULL), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, NULL), (5, 4), (6, 5),
       (7, 6), (8, 9), (9, NULL), (10, NULL), (11, 10), (12, NULL),
       (13, 11), (13, 11), (14, 10), (15, 16), (16, NULL);

INSERT INTO @SubTable (id)
VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (6), (5), (7),
       (8),  -- it does not show
       (13), -- it does not show
       (15); -- it does not show
/* beside 8,13,15 it should add 9,11,14 and 10,16 */

;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
        mt1.id,
        mt1.parentId
    FROM 
        @MasterTable AS mt1
    WHERE 
        mt1.parentId IS NULL
        AND EXISTS (SELECT NULL AS empty
                    FROM @SubTable AS st
                    WHERE st.Id = mt1.id)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        mt2.id,
        mt2.parentId
    FROM 
        @MasterTable AS mt2
    INNER JOIN 
        cte AS c1 ON c1.id = mt2.parentId
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
    c2.id,
    c2.parentId
FROM 
    cte AS c2
ORDER BY 
    id;
```

Comment: what's the subtable for?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu _I would like to retrieve all related records (parent or child, recursively) from the MasterTable based on given SubTable_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the following query suitable for the issue in question?

```
with
  r as(
      select
        m.*, iif(m.parentid is null, 1, 0) p_flag
      from @MasterTable m
      join @SubTable s
        on s.id = m.id
    union all
      select
        m.*, iif(m.parentid is null, 1, r.p_flag)
      from r
      join @MasterTable m
        on (r.p_flag = 1 and m.parentid = r.id) or
           (r.p_flag = 0 and r.parentid = m.id)
)
select distinct
  id, parentid
from r
order by id;
```

**Output:**

```
| id | parentid |
+----+----------+
|  1 | NULL     |
|  2 | 1        |
|  3 | 1        |
|  4 | NULL     |
|  5 | 4        |
|  6 | 5        |
|  7 | 6        |
|  8 | 9        |
|  9 | NULL     |
| 10 | NULL     |
| 11 | 10       |
| 13 | 11       |
| 14 | 10       |
| 15 | 16       |
| 16 | NULL     |
```

Test it online with [rextester.com](https://rextester.com/edit/UFU67518).

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't have 14.  Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 2):

```
;WITH cte
AS (
   SELECT mt1.id,
          mt1.parentId
   FROM @MasterTable AS mt1
   WHERE mt1.parentId IS NULL

   UNION ALL
   SELECT mt2.id,
          mt2.parentId
   FROM @MasterTable AS mt2
       INNER JOIN cte AS c1
           ON c1.id = mt2.parentId

           )
SELECT DISTINCT c2.id,
       c2.parentId
FROM cte AS c2
where 
  EXISTS (
          SELECT 1 AS empty FROM @SubTable AS st
          WHERE   ( st.Id = c2.id or  st.Id = c2.parentId)
         )    
or    
EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 AS empty FROM @MasterTable AS mt
        WHERE  (  c2.Id = mt.parentId or  c2.parentId = mt.parentId)
       )

ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: Thanks, I would like to mark this as the answer, since it returns all the results. However, it takes forever to retrieve results when the `MasterTable` has around 400K records in it. Can you think a way to improve performance?  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this....

```
; with cte as(
      select distinct mas.id, mas.parentId, iif(mas.parentid is null, 1, 0) PId
      from @MasterTable mas inner join @SubTable sub 
        on sub.id in(mas.id, mas.parentid)             ----- create top node having parentid is null
      union all
      select mas.id, mas.parentId, ct.PId
      from cte ct inner join @MasterTable mas
        on (ct.PId = 1 and mas.parentid = ct.id) or 
        (ct.PId = 0 and ct.parentid = mas.id)         ----- create child node for correspoding parentid created above
)
select distinct id, parentid from cte order by id
option (MAXRECURSION  100);        ---- Add Maxrecursion to prevent the infinite loop
```

You can find this link for more info on recursive query in SQL [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). In this link see Example E or above.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't have 14.  Thanks for trying.